# Django -- Admin page is empty HTML

Tags: python, django, admin

I don't exactly know what to provide you with for this one. I am running my project on Xubuntu 12.04 under an Apache2 server. Let me know what information you need.

My admin.py file:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from notendur.models import * # notendur is the application
```

This is what the page looks like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JzeOQ.jpg

This is not how it should look like. It should look like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BbTM.jpg

Comment: As written below, you should configure media and static file locations for Apache, but also remember to run collect static to copy the needed files. The correct apache config file for adding the alias line depends on you server setup. If you have only one site http.conf is the right file. If you have virtual sites, you need to edit a different file.

Comment: Did you make sure to run `python manage.py collectstatic`? EDIT: Ooh beat me to it, @het.oosten

Comment: Thank you for your help. I had mistakenly believed I was running a Virtual host, which I was not. In that case, the Alias goes into httpd.conf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configure your apache server to look for admin MEDIA.

See these location in site packages where admin module is installed.

Configure your apache by adding these lines.

Alias /static/ PATH/TO/LOCATION
Alias /media/ PATH/TO/LOCATION

PATH/TO/LOCATION is your admin media and static file location generally located at site-packages.

Msoni

Comment: Do I add these lines to httpd.conf?

Comment: Also, where is the site-packages? The one in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages is empty.

Comment: @Gudmundur you need to be aware of where your Django was installed. This is really more of a general server admin issue.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I know where it is. There is an admin folder under dist-packages/contrib, which holds /static/. I suppose that is where I should point the static Alias to? What about the media Alias?

Comment: You should make a static and a media direction in your project folder. Then make the correct settings for static files etc. in settings.py. After that you are ready to run collectstatic (this command copies all needed files to the static dir in your project folder. The line in httpd.conf should point to the static dir in your project folder.

Comment: Even dist-packages are considerable. You should not worry about it. consider both site-packages and dist-packages as same to configure apache.